# Cassandra Batches with if not exists condition

Tags: cassandra, database, nosql

When I'm sending batch of inserts to only one table while each row as a unique key with condition if not exists and there is a problem when even if one of the rows exists.

I need to insert the batch per row and not per the whole batch.
Let's say I've a table "users" with only one column "user_name" and contains the row "jhon", Now I'm trying to import new users:

```
BEGIN BATCH
INSERT INTO "users" ("user_name") VALUES ("jhon") IF NOT EXISTS;
INSERT INTO "users" ("user_name") VALUES ("mandy") IF NOT EXISTS;
APPLY BATCH;
```

It will not insert "mandy" because that "jhon" exists, What can I do to isolate them?

I've a lot of rows to insert about 100-200K so I need to use batch.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

First: what you describe is documented as intended behavior:

> In Cassandra 2.0.6 and later, you can batch conditional updates introduced as lightweight transactions in Cassandra 2.0. Only updates made to the same partition can be included in the batch because the underlying Paxos implementation works at the granularity of the partition. You can group updates that have conditions with those that do not, but when a single statement in a batch uses a condition, the entire batch is committed using a single Paxos proposal, as if all of the conditions contained in the batch apply.

That basically confirms: your updates are to different partitions, so only one Paxos proposal is going to be used, which means the entire batch will succeed, or none of it will.

That said, with Cassandra, batches aren't meant to speed up and bulk load - they're meant to create pseudo-atomic logical operations. From http://docs.datastax.com/en/cql/3.1/cql/cql_using/useBatch.html :

> Batches are often mistakenly used in an attempt to optimize performance. Unlogged batches require the coordinator to manage inserts, which can place a heavy load on the coordinator node. If other nodes own partition keys, the coordinator node needs to deal with a network hop, resulting in inefficient delivery. Use unlogged batches when making updates to the same partition key.
>
> The coordinator node might also need to work hard to process a logged batch while maintaining consistency between tables. For example, upon receiving a batch, the coordinator node sends batch logs to two other nodes. In the event of a coordinator failure, the other nodes retry the batch. The entire cluster is affected. Use a logged batch to synchronize tables, as shown in this example:

In your schema, each INSERT is to a different partition, which is going to add a LOT of load on your coordinator.

You can run your 200k inserts with a client with async executes, and they'll run quite fast - probably as fast (or faster) as you'd see with a batch.

Comment: Thanks, I've made the changes hopefully Cassandra will handle 200K requests fast (async calls).